# Is it possible to add an alias in bash that allows tab completion?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have lots of log files in a deeper directory like so:

```
/my/deep/path/to/log/files/
                           foo-2016-10-10.log
                           foo-2016-10-11.log
                           bar-2016-10-10.log
                           bar-2016-10-11.log
```

Many times a day I find myself tailing different logs like so:

```
tail -fn 100 /my/deep/path/to/log/files/foo-2016-10-10.log
```

Is it possible to alias everything but the final file? **And** allow tab completion to get me the rest of the way?

For example, I'd love to type `tl` (short for tail log) and the specific log file I'm looking for like so:

```
$ tl foo
      [HIT TAB KEY]
$ tl foo-2016-10-1
      [HIT 1 and TAB KEY]
$ tl foo-2016-10-11.log
```

Is this possible in bash? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: SO is for programming questions. Questions about **using** the shell belong on SuperUser.com.

Comment: This type of command completion generally requires some scripting, though.

Comment: As an aside, I'd tend to suggest getting in the habit of using functions rather than aliases -- it's only slightly longer to type `tl() { tail -fn 100 /my/deep/path/to/log/files/"$1"; }`, but it gives you considerably more flexibility: For instance, whereas you can't mutate arguments with an alias but only prepend them, you can easily do so with a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much a clone of Charles Duffy's answer (with the only difference that he uses globs and I'm using `compgen` — which is probably the way completions are (badly) designed to be written):

```
_tl_COMPDIR=/my/deep/path/to/log/files/
_comp_tl() {
   local IFS=$'\n'
   COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f -- "$_tl_COMPDIR$2") )
   COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]#"$_tl_COMPDIR"}" )
}

tl() (
   cd -- "$_tl_COMPDIR" && tail -fn 100 "$@"
)

complete -o nospace -o filenames -F _comp_tl tl
```

Comment: Perfectly accomplished, very concise, but still readable. Works exactly as expected: `tl ` [with tab-completion]. Thank you.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, could I ask for some feedback on my answer (ie. in comments there), in terms of what it's getting wrong?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: nothing wrong in your answer (and I upvoted it), now that you edited it! the first version was a mess, though `:)`.

Comment: Ahh. Yes, the first version certainly was. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: anyway, completions in Bash are really badly designed and badly break with funny characters in filenames. The completion functions are designed to be used with `compgen` to populate the `COMPREPLY` array, and it's really really bad. Hopefully Chet will fix that for Bash 5, in a few decades!

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit ugly, but this does the job:

```
_tl_log_path=/my/deep/path/to/log/files

_tl_completions() {
  COMPREPLY=( "${_tl_log_path}/$2"* )
  COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]#${_tl_log_path}/}" )
  if [[ ${COMPREPLY[0]} = "$2*" ]]; then
    COMPREPLY=( )
  fi
}
complete -F _tl_completions -o filenames tl
```

---

As for your `tl`, I'd suggest implementing it as such:

```
tl() {
  # generate an array of arguments to pass to tail
  local -a args=( )

  # iterate over each argument given to the function
  for arg; do
    if [[ -e "$_tl_log_path/$arg" ]]; then
      # if a like-name file exists under _tl_log_path, add that filename as an argument
      args+=( "$_tl_log_path/$arg" )
    else
      # otherwise, add that argument exactly as it already exists
      args+=( "$arg" )
    fi
  done
  # ...and, finally, execute the tail command.
  tail -f "${args[@]}"
}
```

...though you could also go cheap and easy:

```
tl() (
  cd "$_tl_log_path" || exit
  exec tail -f "$@"
)
```

---

To explain:

- `complete -F funcname cmdname` indicates that the shell function `funcname` should be called to determine how to complete the command `cmdname`. `-o filenames` further indicates that the results should be treated as filenames.
- `COMPREPLY` is a shell array which the completion function is expected to fill out with possible completions.
- `COMPREPLY=( "${_tl_log_path}/$2"* )` expands the given content as a glob (because the `*` is, intentionally, outside the quotes).
- `COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]#${_tl_log_path}/" )` then strips the log directory as a prefix from each result in the array.
- Checking whether `[[ ${COMPREPLY[0]} = "$2*" ]]` (with the asterisk **inside** the quotes, on this occasion), detects the case where no possible glob expansion results existed, and where (thus) the glob expanded to itself (assuming that the shell's configuration via `shopt` is at defaults).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simply switch to that directory before executing the command.

```
$ cd /my/deep/path/to/log/files/
$ tl <tab>
```